# Where do I find the "constructor arguments" for a contract deployed with Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan, abi, verify

When try to verify token, I dont know what to put in for this line:

> Constructor Arguments ABI-encoded (For contracts that accept constructor parameters)

I made token after looking at a YouTube video on how to do it.

I used this code:

https://gitlab.com/pedram31/cryptocoopx-ccx/blob/master/ccx-src.sol

And pasted it here:

http://remix.ethereum.org/#optimize=true&version=soljson-v0.4.24+commit.e67f0147.js

Now I have no idea how to verify my token:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x08e3ec9a41318c26fcd6b9d26feba612628aee28e52e855a542a864fc41ef01e

I saw that there you can copy some numbers after `0029` but there is nothing after `0029`.

I also saw that I can use https://abi.hashex.org/ or this https://abi.sonnguyen.ws/, but I do not know how to use these websites.

Comment: This is an error I get when I only paste the code and try to verify: "Error! Unable to verify source code
Missing Constructor Arguments for function CCXTokenERC20(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol)"

Comment: What values did you use for initial supply, token name, and token symbol?

Comment: I used 10.000.000.000 for initial supply, token name is Mooneta and token symbol is MNTX

Comment: use sol-verifier to get rid of encoding overhead : https://www.npmjs.com/package/sol-verifier

Answer (score 1):

Using your constructor function:

```
CCXTokenERC20(uint256 initialSupply, string tokenName, string tokenSymbol)
```

And you initial parameters:

```
10000000000, Mooneta, MNTX
```

You can use https://abi.hashex.org/ like so:

[image]

This results in the following value which you should be able to use:

```
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002540be400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000074d6f6f6e6574610000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000044d4e545800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you for help, sir. I used that code you provided me here and i got this error now: https://i.imgur.com/KZn2l4X.png

Comment: I might look at a more in depth verification tutorial [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/how-to-verify-and-publish-on-etherscan-52cf25312945).

Comment: I have read the article you send me, but I still don't understand what I need to do in order to fix this error I am getting.